# How to capture score recaptcha v3 score in wordpress while using contact form 7?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Please help for to capture a recatcha v3 score in worpdress.

I am getting score below object  but how to get from this object

```
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

WPCF7_Submission Object
(
[pocket:protected] => Array
        (
            [recaptcha] => Array
                (
                    [version] => 3.0
                    [threshold] => 0.5
                    [response] => Array
                        (
                            [success] => 1
                            [challenge_ts] => 2023-06-22T10:30:41Z
                            [hostname] => staging.bonoboz.in
                            [score] => 0.9
                            [action] => contactform
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Did you go look up what methods that class provides? https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/contact-form-7/function/WPCF7_Submission

Answer (score 2):

The WPCF7_Submission object contains the data submitted through the form. The recaptcha array contains the reCAPTCHA data, and the response array within it contains the score field.

You can access this score like so:

```
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ($submission) {
    $recaptcha = $submission->get_meta('recaptcha');
    if ($recaptcha) {
        $score = $recaptcha['response']['score'];
        // do something with $score
    }
}
```

In this code, `$submission->get_meta('recaptcha')` retrieves the recaptcha data from the submission. Then, `$recaptcha['response']['score']` retrieves the score from the reCAPTCHA response. Now, `$score` contains the reCAPTCHA v3 score.

Please note that this example assumes you're using the Contact Form 7 plugin with the reCAPTCHA module enabled and correctly configured to use reCAPTCHA v3. Also, this code should be placed in an appropriate location where it will be executed after form submission, such as a form submission hook or custom form processing code.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 (at least as of January 2024) stores the last recaptcha score in a private variable that can be accessed via a public getter function. So I had luck with the following approach:

```php
$recaptcha_service = WPCF7_RECAPTCHA::get_instance();
$score = $recaptcha_service->get_last_score();
```

For reference, this was running from the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action in my case.